# How to Mock Oauth2AuthorizedClientManager in Feign Interceptor using Junit and Mockito?

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

@Autowired
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {

```
return requestTemplate -> {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("keycloak")
                                                                    .principal(authentication)
                                                                    .build();
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient = this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest);
    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = authorizedClient.getAccessToken();

    requestTemplate.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + accessToken.getTokenValue());
};
```

}

How to Mock Oauth2AuthorizedClientManager in Feign Interceptor using Junit and Mockito?

Comment: can you please add more details as to what you are trying to do and what is the error you are getting? What is the original code that you are trying to mock?